# How to print Doc string of python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In one Django scripts and for each script I need to print it's name and docstring.

I have tried like this:

```
foo = __import__('/home/piyush/foo.py')
mydocstring = foo.__doc__
```

But it's giving me error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Can you help me how do I do that.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM, I have check the ink you suggested, does it means I can't do that because in single file I have 2-3 classes but the thing is I don't want class's doc string I want file's doc string.

Comment: You can use `sys.path.append('/home/piyush/')`, Then you can import your file by using `import foo`.

Comment: Actually that are Django scripts so when I did `import sys` `sys.path.append('/home/piyush/)` and  `import activityArea` it's throwing errors `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings`

Comment: Then you should execute it inside django environment.

Comment: Thanks bro I should have test it in `django shell`.

Comment: I am updating my question , please add your answer.